# How can I have a responsive line '-----'?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I would like to have a kind of line break '-----------' between two divs.

Is there a way using bootstrap/css to make this responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the css property: `border-bottom` together with the border style: `dotted` to achieve the effect. Or the `solid` to have a solid line.

Example:

CSS:

```
.first {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
}

.second {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    <p>
        This is first
    </p>
</div>

<div class="second">
    <p>
        This is second
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was searching for!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the

```
<hr />
```

tag. If your divs start out side-by-side and then stack on smaller screens, you'll want to use media queries to decide when to display the horizontal rules.

Bootstrap has built-in classes to help you do this. They are documented [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) under the "Responsive utility classes" heading.

Comment: I need the line to be dotted though, is there a way using hr?

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realize that was what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric Zaporzan said, you could use the horizontal rule tag `<hr/>` to draw a line across the page. However if you want it strictly between the two divs then you could simply use `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` on the higher div.